# Browser issue while generating dynamic table in java script?

Tags: javascript, html, browser, html-table, cross-browser

I am generating grid on image of specified dimension using Javascript.
I have given user to select size of grid from drop down list if user select 10 x 10 ,then I am generating 10 x 10 grid on image.
My problem is my code works fine on Google Chrome but not working on Mozilla and IE, problem is that Mozilla and IE not showing grid on image.
I am attaching screen shot of Chrome and Mozilla.

Following is my html page:

```
     <html>
      <div style="position: absolute; left: 20px; " id="more_clicky1">
      <IMG   src="images/ignore_area.jpg" id="ia"> </IMG>
      </div>

     <div style="position:absolute; left: 20px; " id="more_clicky">
    <table name="GridTable" style=""  id="GridTable" border = "2"  cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">                             
    </table>
   </div>
   </html>
```

And my code to generate grid on image in Javascript is as follows:

```
    function Create_Table(trow,tcol,noc)
    {
    var wid=document.getElementById("ia").width;
    var hei=document.getElementById("ia").height;

    var cwidth=wid/tcol;
    var cheight=hei/trow;


    var mytable = document.getElementById('GridTable');
    rr=mytable.rows.length;
    while(rr--)
    {
        mytable.deleteRow(rr);
        //alert(rr);
    }
    var temp;
    var cell;   
    for (var r = 0; r <trow; r++) 
    {
        temp=noc;
        var row = mytable.insertRow(r);
        for (var c = 0; c <tcol; c++)
        {
            cell=row.insertCell(c);
            cell.id='td'+temp;
            cell.style.width =cwidth;
            cell.style.height =cheight;
            //alert(cell.id);
            //cell.innerHTML='&nbsp;';
            cell.className="dynamic";

            with ({ n: cell.id }) 
            {
                cell.onclick = function()
                {
                        bcolor1('red',n);
                };
                cell.onmousemove=function()
                {
                    bcolor('red',n);
                }   
            }                                                         
            temp++;
        }
        noc=noc-tcol;
    }

    }
```

Comment: Generated HTML does not appear valid. I would first try with valid HTML / XHTML...

Comment: thanks for reply I got the solution, in the java script code I just removed comment of line cell.innerHTML='&nbsp;'; now it is generating grid on image.